# extract serialized user session data

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, symfony-1.4

i have a symfony 1.4 application that I just changed to save the session data in a session table in a mysql database.

Here is an example of the serialized mysql table session_data field.

```
symfony/user/sfUser/lastRequest|i:1447469750;
symfony/user/sfUser/authenticated|b:1;
symfony/user/sfUser/credentials|a:0:{}
symfony/user/sfUser/attributes|a:2:
{s:30:"symfony/user/sfUser/attributes";
a:3:{s:12:"current_page";
s:6:"splash";s:15:"logged_in_token";
s:31:"e9psz6e3iko4scsk0c4k4wckwk4k0k4";
s:25:"available_credits_session";
i:0;}s:19:"sfGuardSecurityUser";
a:1:{s:7:"user_id";s:1:"1";}}
symfony/user/sfUser/culture|s:2:"en";
```

I would like to extract two pieces of information from this serialized data.

1) the logged_in_token id which I am using so the users real user id is not exposed.

and

2) the user_id which is the actual user id.

The reason I need this information is the application requirement is that they can only have one active session at a time.

So if there is two of the same user id in the session table I will be using this information for log out or time out the previous session.

it seems to be a specific "symfony way" of serializing the data.

Any idea on how to extract this information in node or javascript would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way this data is serialized is not specific to `symfony`, it is specific to `php`. Depending on `session.serialize_handler` setting in `php.ini` php serializes session data in different way. Default value for that setting is just `php` which seems to be used in your case.

I use following method in `php` to escape this encoding - it outputs regular array with data. It's nothing `php` specific here so you can easily port it to javascript:
(however best solution would be to do "unescaping" before saving this data to database, then you won't need to do this on javascript side)

```
function unserializePhp($sessionData)
{
    $returnData = array();
    $offset = 0;
    while ($offset < strlen($sessionData)) {
        if (!strstr(substr($sessionData, $offset), '|')) {
            throw new Exception('invalid data, remaining: ' . substr($sessionData, $offset));
        }
        $pos = strpos($sessionData, '|', $offset);
        $num = $pos - $offset;
        $varname = substr($sessionData, $offset, $num);
        $offset += $num + 1;
        $data = unserialize(substr($sessionData, $offset));
        $returnData[$varname] = $data;
        $offset += strlen(serialize($data));
    }

    return $returnData;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I have been trying to figure that out for so long it's embarrassing. I edited with working symfony code based on your suggestion. Thank you so much.